# What do these horse racing terms mean?

Tags: terminology, horse-racing

What does it mean if a horse race is described as:

- Hcap,
- HCap Hrd,
- Mdn Stks,
- Nov Hrd,
- Beg Chs,
- Listed,
- INHF,
- Sell Stks

Answer (score 7):

Hcap - Handicap

Hcap HRd - Handicap Hurdle

Mdn Stks - Maiden Stakes

Nov Hrd - Novice Hurdle

Listed - Just below `Group` class

Not sure on the other three

For more information: http://www.flatstats.co.uk/horse-race-information.html

Answer (score 1):

Beg Chs = beginner chase (higher barriers)

Sell stks = sell stakes (horses available for purchase)

INHF  = Intermediate National Hunt Flat
(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Hunt_flat_race)